# C# My BindingSource filter won't seems to update dataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

I've tried updating dynamically my datasource on my datagrid, but it keeps returning no value... Note : i've already closed my connection to my SQL database and am tried to filter it through a textbox textchanged method (at each change, it would dynamically filter the Binding).

It seems my textbox and everything is populated at each step i've checked each propert, and yes, my column to be filtered is verb

```
void txtChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox tbTemp = (TextBox)sender;
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dataSet.dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

                        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                        bs.DataSource = dt;
                        bs.Filter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", "Verb", tbTemp.Text);

                        dataGrid.DataSource = bs;
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the line… `dataSet.dataAdapter.Fill(dt);` … doing? If `dataSet` IS a true `DataSet` object, I do not see a `dataAdapter` property. I get a compile time error here stating such. Is `dataset` some other type of object? Whatever it is, it is NOT filling the `DataTable` `dt`. Also, it seems odd to “re-fill” the data source each time the user types a character into the text box. I am confident you do not want to do this. I suggest removing the code that “re-fills” the data source as it appears unnecessary.

Comment: If your DGV is originally bound to a BindingSource, store that BindingSource (use a Field a whatever fits). When the Text of the Control changes, simply set the Filter of the BindingSource. Or, use the `KeyDown` event to handle the `Enter` key and set the `Filter` only when the User is done typing and presses `Enter`. If you don't want to store a BindingSource, you can always cast the DGV.DataSource to BindingSource and set its Filter: `(dataGrid.DatSource as BindingSource).Filter = $"ColumnName LIKE '%{tbTemp.Text}%'"`. See that the `LIKE` syntax matches the Column data type.

Comment: Oh my god, guys. it works like a charm now! Thanks for the help, i would like to help any other people with this issue. It was sooooo complex... Your solution guided me towards the truth :

BindingSource datamember property needs to be set to table. Here is my correct code :

void txtChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
TextBox tbTemp = (TextBox)sender;

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, guys. it works like a charm now! Thanks for the help, i would like to help any other people with this issue. It was sooooo complex... Your solution guided me towards the truth :

BindingSource datamember property needs to be set to table. Here is my correct code :

```
void txtChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox tbTemp = (TextBox)sender;
    dataSet.bdSource.Filter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'",
    strTemp[Int16.Parse(tb.Name)], tbTemp.Text);
    //Use table name instead of verb
    dataSet.bdSource.DataMember = "Verbe";


    dataGrid.DataSource = null;
    dataGrid.DataSource = dataSet.bdSource;
    dataGrid.Refresh();
}
```